# как изменить структуру обьекта используя reduce()?

Tags: javascript

Как изменить структуру обьекта с такого:

```
   const data = {
      "22-10-2015": { 'id': {}, 'id1': {}, 'id2': {}},
      "23-10-2015": { 'id3': {}, 'id4': {}, 'id5': {}},
      "24-11-2015": { 'id6': {}, 'id7': {}, 'id8': {}},
        ...
    }
```

на такой

```
{ 'id': {}, 'id1': {}, 'id2': {}, 'id3': {}, 'id4': {}, 'id5': {}, 'id6': {}, 'id7': {}, 'id8': {}, ...}
```

Используя `Array.reduce()`:

```
Object.keys(data).reduce((a,c) => ...)
```

Comment: Если честно, не понятный формат данных. Если это JSON, то он - не валидный. Если это Array(), то тоже не проходит синтаксис. Если это объект JS, то тоже не правильно указан синтаксис.

Comment: @Kosmos немного исправил вопрос, нодеюсь это внесло ясность. Спасибо

Comment: @dev_jun, в текущем виде в объекте data будет только одно поле `date` которому будет соответствовать последнее определение. Это точно объект или все-таки массив должен быть?

Comment: @Grundy Мне приходит с бд json с полями "data" в каждом есть по несколько id, мне нужно мигрировать эту бд , что бы были только id без дат

Comment: @dev_jun, почему не решать это на уровне выдачи с db? Пример приведенный в вопросе при разборе в Объект уберет **все** одноименные поля `date` кроме последнего

Comment: @Grundy мой фейл, там поля `date` разные, пример: '22-07-2015'

Comment: @dev_jun, тогда другое дело. Поправь пример в вопросе

Comment: @Grundy исправил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Нужно получить все значения из начального объекта, для этого можно воспользоваться методом [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
2. Полученный массив нужно свернуть в объект. Сделать это можно с помощью метода [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Пример реализации:

```js
const data = {
  "22-10-2015": {
    'id': {},
    'id1': {},
    'id2': {}
  },
  "23-10-2015": {
    'id3': {},
    'id4': {},
    'id5': {}
  },
  "24-11-2015": {
    'id6': {},
    'id7': {},
    'id8': {}
  },
}

var result = Object.values(data)
  .reduce((acc, cur) =>
    Object.keys(cur)
    .reduce((curAcc, curKey) => (curAcc[curKey] = cur[curKey], curAcc), acc), {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще сделать таким образом

```
var result = Object.values(data).reduce((p, c) => ({...p, ...c}), {})
```

Меньше кода

Comment: @Grundy, могут ли быть проблемы с такой реализацией?

Comment: Не больше чем с моей, так же можно `Object.assign` использовать, там где еще не поддерживается `{...obj}`. По сути вложенный reduce в итоге и делает `{...obj}`

Comment: _sidenote_: пользователь не получит оповещения, если к нему обратились не под его вопросом/ответом и если он не оставлял под этим вопросом/ответом комментариев :)

Comment: @Grundy понял, буду иметь ввиду, спасибо:)

Comment: Не забудь отметить галочкой ответ.